# I get the error: websocket connection closed

Tags: android, ios, flutter, connection, artificial-intelligence

I try to make an app, that i can ask questions and the ai will automaticly awnsers those questions but i do not see any responds from the ai. So looked into it. I made some code to see what was wrong and i came to the conclusion that the WebSocket connection was closed. Does anyone know how to fix this issue.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart' as ws;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Chat App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'My Chat App', key: GlobalKey()),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({required Key key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late ws.WebSocketChannel socket;
  TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();
  List<ChatMessage> messages = [];
  bool isConnected = false;
  late String errorMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connectToWebSocket();
  }

  void connectToWebSocket() async {
    try {
      socket = ws.WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse("wss://chat.openai.com/api/chat"));
      socket.stream.listen((data) {
        setState(() {
          try {
            // Parse the received message into a ChatMessage object
            final message = ChatMessage.fromJson(json.decode(data));
            messages.add(message);
          } catch (error) {
            errorMessage = 'Error parsing message: $error';
          }
        });
      }, onError: (error) {
        setState(() {
          errorMessage = 'Error receiving message: $error';
        });
      }, onDone: () {
        setState(() {
          errorMessage = 'WebSocket connection closed';
        });
      });
      setState(() {
        isConnected = true;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        errorMessage = 'Error connecting to WebSocket: $error';
      });
    }
  }
  void sendMessage() {
    if (messageController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      socket.sink.add(messageController.text);
      messageController.clear();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child : Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: messages.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final message = messages[index];
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(message.sender, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  Text(message.text),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        if (errorMessage != null) Text(errorMessage),
        TextField(
          controller: messageController,
          onSubmitted: (value) => sendMessage(),
        ),
        if (isConnected) ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: sendMessage,
          child: const Text('Send'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
        ),
    );
  }
}

// ChatMessage class and fromJson method
class ChatMessage {
  final String sender;
  final String text;

  ChatMessage({required this.sender, required this.text});

  factory ChatMessage.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ChatMessage(
      sender: json['sender'],
      text: json['text'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just came to know why the connection is closed. It is due to a run-time exception '**WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://chat.openai.com:0/api/chat#' was not upgraded to WebSocket**'

The issue seems to be on the backend as per the info below link. My team in the office actually fixed the same type of exception. I will inform you after knowing from them.
https://github.com/zino-hofmann/graphql-flutter/issues/480